# How to know which API calls are made to my code (SERVER) ? When working with a Native Android Developer

Tags: rest, api, kotlin

For the first time I have started working with a Android Developer. 
I am writing for him CodeIgniter RESTful API.

I just want to ask that how can I know what are the POST variables he sending to my API when hitting a particular one.

Because many times he is sending a different format of POST while my ready function is expecting some different POST formats or sometime totally different POST.

Is there any way I can know what and which POST formats he is posting on my functions. So that if he is sending a wrong format I can immediately tell him to send the inputs in a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my problem. I am maintaining a log file now, which keeps on logging all the API hits on my server. With POSTs sent along with API call.